# Confused about prediction output for glmnet package cv.glmnet model

Tags: r, logistic, glmnet

I am using the glmnet package to perform logistic regression on a dataset.
The x.train and x.test data is a simple dataset of numbers.
y.train and y.test is data with categories "Coffee" and "Tea".
Basically the prediction needs to be either "Coffee" or "Tea"

My first question is that do I need to factor the y datasets? I haven't factored them yet.

Secondly, and mainly, this is the problem:

My code is as follows:

```
lr.fit<-cv.glmnet(x.train, y.train, type.measure="deviance", family = "binomial")
lr.predicted<-predict(lr.fit, s=c("lambda.1se", "lambda.min"), newx=x.test)
```

However, when I see the output of the lr.predicted variable, I see a list of numbers. I am asking this question because, I was actually expecting predictions like "Coffee", "Tea", "Coffee", "Coffee", "Tea", ........... and so on.

Kindly guide in the right direction. I am a beginner with R and machine learning, so apologies for being an amateur.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the reference page for [glmnet](https://glmnet.stanford.edu/reference/glmnet.html):

> **y**    response variable. Quantitative for family="gaussian", or
> family="poisson" (non-negative counts). For family="binomial" should
> be either a factor with two levels, or a two-column matrix of counts
> or proportions (the second column is treated as the target class; for
> a factor, the last level in alphabetical order is the target class).

For the `predict` [function](https://glmnet.stanford.edu/reference/predict.glmnetfit.html):

> **type**    Type of prediction required. Type "link" gives the linear predictors (eta scale); Type "response" gives the fitted values (mu
> scale). Type "coefficients" computes the coefficients at the requested
> values for s. Type "nonzero" returns a list of the indices of the
> nonzero coefficients for each value of s.

I believe what you are looking for is `type = "class"`, to get the class with highest probability.

For future references, remember to provide a reproducible example of your issue (both code *and* data).